# Gulp not being invoked on project build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gulp

According to step 5 of [this tutorial](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/), when I build my project Gulp should copy the contents of my `node_modules` folder into the `wwwroot`.

It's not doing it though.  I've tried ticking the boxes in the project properties page (no idea if that should make a different or not though).

[image: tick boxes on project build are ticked]

The `gulpfile.js` looks like so:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');

var destPath = './wwwroot/libs/';

// Delete the dist directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(destPath)
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task("scriptsNStyles", () => {
    gulp.src([
            'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**',
            'jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
            'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.*js',
    ], {
        cwd: "node_modules/**"
    })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/libs"));

    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/css'));
});

var tsProject = ts.createProject('scripts/tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('ts', function (done) {
    //var tsResult = tsProject.src()
    var tsResult = gulp.src([
            "scripts/*.ts"
    ])
        .pipe(ts(tsProject), undefined, ts.reporter.fullReporter());
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/appScripts'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['watch.ts']);

gulp.task('watch.ts', ['ts'], function () {
    return gulp.watch('scripts/*.ts', ['ts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scriptsNStyles', 'watch']);
```

To be honest, I'm struggling to debug as I don't know what bit should be making Gulp be invoked on build.

Any clarification would be very helpful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a step missing from the tutorial. You need to set up a binding to run your Gulp task when the project is built.

To do this open the `Task Runner Explorer` window (View -> Other Windows -> Task Runner Explorer). This should list all the Gulp tasks in your `gulpfile.js`. Right click the one you want to run upon build (probably `default`) and select Bindings -> After Build. You can also run the tasks manually by right clicking and selecting 'Run'.

[image: Task Runner Explorer Bindings]

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.  It also missed out that the `() => {...}` won't compile and that you need a `tsconfig.json` in the `scripts` directory to work.  Just added those too and everything seems good.